# Why am I getting error Import Error when I try to make a model on PYMC in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pymc

I am trying to make a fairly simple model which is just checking correlation between features of iris data set. I have followed the instruction for installing PYMC from the documentation and have made an environment with it in anaconda. It imports pymc just fine.

**Problems**:

1. It does not import theano. (Saying no such module exists)
2. When I try to run the model it gives me import error (image attached below)

For example I am trying to run this model:

```
with pm.Model() as pooled:
    # Latent pooled effect size
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", 0, sigma=1e6)

    obs = pm.Normal("obs", mu, sigma=sigma, observed=y)

    trace_p = pm.sample(2000)
```

This is a demo model I took from the PYMC documentation. It should work right?

[image]

It of course does not!

Here is the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File path\anaconda3\envs\pymc_env\Lib\site-packages\pytensor\link\c\lazylinker_c.py:79
     78         if version != actual_version:
---> 79             raise ImportError(
     80                 "Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file."
     81                 f" Looking for version {version}, but found {actual_version}. "
     82                 f"Extra debug information: force_compile={force_compile}, _need_reload={_need_reload}"
     83             )
     84 except ImportError:

ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.212, but found None. Extra debug information: force_compile=False, _need_reload=True
```

I tried everything making a new environment. Tried CHATGPT it too but it does not give a solution that has worked till now :(

I tried running this line in my anaconda cli:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pymc3
```

But this is what I get

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt
```